# Convert the first string element of a list of lists to a tuple

Tags: python, list, data-analysis, data-science, nested-lists

```
ohlc = df.values.tolist()
```

gives me this list of lists:

```
[['2018-04-09', 7044.32, 7178.11, 6661.99, 6770.73],
 ['2018-04-08', 6919.98, 7111.56, 6919.98, 7023.52],
 ['2018-04-07', 6630.51, 7050.54, 6630.51, 6911.09],
 ['2018-04-06', 6815.96, 6857.49, 6575.0, 6636.32],
 ['2018-04-05', 6848.65, 6933.82, 6644.8, 6811.47],...]
```

For further analytics i need to convert the Datestring of each list to a a tuple like (2018,04,09)

thx

Comment: Did an answer below help? Feel free to accept an answer (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can split a string by a certain delimiter like so.

```
>>> s = '2018-04-09'
>>> s.split('-')
['2018', '04', '09']
```

You can also turn a `list` into a `tuple` by type-casting it:

```
>>> L = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> tuple(L)
('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Note that these functions are immutable - they do not change the object, they return the result (so you'd need to do `L = tuple(L)` for example).

I hope this helps your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [@TerryA's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50040003/9209546), you can do most of the manipulation upstream in `pandas`:

```
lst = [['2018-04-09', 7044.32, 7178.11, 6661.99, 6770.73],
       ['2018-04-08', 6919.98, 7111.56, 6919.98, 7023.52],
       ['2018-04-07', 6630.51, 7050.54, 6630.51, 6911.09],
       ['2018-04-06', 6815.96, 6857.49, 6575.0, 6636.32],
       ['2018-04-05', 6848.65, 6933.82, 6644.8, 6811.47]]

# we start with a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)

# reassign column 0 with list comprehension + conversion to int
df[0] = [tuple(int(i) for i in x.split('-')) for x in df[0]]

# extract list
res = df.values.tolist()

[[(2018, 4, 9), 7044.32, 7178.11, 6661.99, 6770.73],
 [(2018, 4, 8), 6919.98, 7111.56, 6919.98, 7023.52],
 [(2018, 4, 7), 6630.51, 7050.54, 6630.51, 6911.09],
 [(2018, 4, 6), 6815.96, 6857.49, 6575.0, 6636.32],
 [(2018, 4, 5), 6848.65, 6933.82, 6644.8, 6811.47]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `list comprehension` and modifying the list in place:

```
lists = [['2018-04-09', 7044.32, 7178.11, 6661.99, 6770.73],
         ['2018-04-08', 6919.98, 7111.56, 6919.98, 7023.52],
         ['2018-04-07', 6630.51, 7050.54, 6630.51, 6911.09],
         ['2018-04-06', 6815.96, 6857.49, 6575.0, 6636.32],
         ['2018-04-05', 6848.65, 6933.82, 6644.8, 6811.47]]

lists[:] = [[tuple(item.split('-')) if isinstance(item, str) else item for item in sub] 
            for sub in lists] 

lists

[[('2018', '04', '09'), 7044.32, 7178.11, 6661.99, 6770.73],
 [('2018', '04', '08'), 6919.98, 7111.56, 6919.98, 7023.52],
 [('2018', '04', '07'), 6630.51, 7050.54, 6630.51, 6911.09],
 [('2018', '04', '06'), 6815.96, 6857.49, 6575.0, 6636.32],
 [('2018', '04', '05'), 6848.65, 6933.82, 6644.8, 6811.47]]
```